# blobstore upload code not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

```
<body>
    <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" 
          method="post" 
         enctype="multipart/form-data"
    >
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

the above code throws a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on compilation.I can't understand and what is blobstoreService in the above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the header

<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>

<%
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
%>

Upload Test
    
    
        " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">